# RSA безопасная передача публичного ключа

Tags: rsa, key

Всем привет, ребят! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в этом:

Необходимо установить безопасное соединение клиента с сервером (java приложение)

**МНЕ ЛИШЬ НУЖНО ПОНЯТЬ МОЖНО ЛИ И ЕСЛИ МОЖНО ТО КАК?**

Как мне передать безопасно публичный ключ на сервер, чтобы пока он шел, никто не смог его подменить, и тем самым стать "посредником" который будет сделать и записывать все что проходит через сеть

Возьмём провайдера, для примера, то он по идеи, чисто физически может сделать так:

Клиент генерирует ключи, отправляет свой Публичный ключ на сервер, НО провайдер сохраняет этот ключ и создаёт свою пару ключей, а после, отправляет свой Публичный ключ на сервер

Сервер в свою очередь, отправляет обратно Клиенту что то, но когда это проходит через провайдера, то он расшифровывает то что прислал сервер, сохраняет, зашифровывает публичным ключем клиента и отправляет ему же...

Как быть в таком случае? Как избежать такой схемы?

Comment: Чтобы установить безопасное соединение, просто возьмите TLS и не пытайтесь изобретать свои велосипеды

Comment: @andreymal , получается, если я буду использовать TLS то связь эту никак не взломать / прослушать ?

Comment: Вопрос в том, какие сертификаты в TLS вы используете. Сертификаты для того и придуманы, что бы была некая третья сторона, которой все доверяют и которая подписывает своим закрытым ключом ваши ключи. И вы, убедившись, что ваши сертификаты подписаны этой третьей стороной, которой вы доверяете, могли быть уверены, что ключ не выпущен кем то посередине. В принципе вы можете конечно не использовать сертификаты (ключи), подписанные официальным центром сертификации, а собственные, подписанные вашим центром сертификации, публичный ключ которого заранее отдается обоим сторонам соединения